# getJSON does not work

Tags: php, jquery, getjson

My code in main.php is like this:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('abc.php?valueOne=value1&valueTwo=value2', function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
      });
```

in abc.php there are text values and numbers as result which I want to display in main.php

The problem is if it is a number then it is shown in the alert alert(data) else if there are text nothing is working.

Am totally confused about this. Any solutions?

Comment: How are you generating the JSON?

Comment: I didn't get you, please.

Comment: Post the contents of `abc.php`.

Comment: Also, `);` and `});` are missing here.

Comment: In abc.php I retrieve data from my table.

Comment: @JerryJones Post the code of abc.php and its output.

Comment: @JerryJones: Right, but how are you returning it? The JSON format has a specific structure.

Comment: Well, if I write like this:
<?php
$dataOne = "1234";
$dataTwo = "Abcd";

echo $dataOne . $dataTwo;

?>

Nothing is working. If I omit or change the value of $dataTwo to any number it works.

Comment: can you check the browser console for any errors, also register a fail callback and see whether error is coming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.getJSON` expects a JSON response, so you should have this kind of PHP code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'one' => "1234",
    'two' => "Abcd",
));
```

Then, inside JavaScript:

```
function(data) {
    alert(data.one);
    alert(data.two);
}
```

Comment: Also, consider `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: Edit and comment timing collision.

Comment: Man, you saved my life. Thanks a lot to all "You's" for your valuable time and efforts. a BIG THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$.getJSON('abc.php?valueOne=value1&valueTwo=value2', function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
```

With

```
$.getJSON('abc.php?valueOne=value1&valueTwo=value2', function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

there was missing `);`