# can getJSON() be used for php?

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is the JQuery code loaded over click but the callback function isn't working:

```
$.getJSON("load_img.php", {"id":"start"} , function(json){
     alert(json);
});
```

PHP code gives me this output:

```
[
    {"img_name":"shiva.jpg","img_id":"1"}, 
    {"img_name":"shiva.jpg","img_id":"2"},
    {"img_name":"Recoverd_jpg_file(4).jpg","img_id":"3"}, 
    {"img_name":"Recoverd_jpg_file(542).jpg","img_id":"4"}
]
```

I cannot load any PHP pages from getJSON() function...i downloaded sample source code from [here][1]

[1]: http://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/ and have run it on browser but it doesnt work still...
any help would be much appreciated!!!Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getJSON does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786120/getjson-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer today...no `<html>` tags should be included in the code to be outputted... it should only contain starting and ending php tags i.e.

```
<?php
//your code or codes
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    <button id="try" type="button">Try</button>

<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    $.getJSON("load_img.php", {"id":"start"}, function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
             alert(field.img_name);
        });
    });
```

i is the field name and field is value. Please check and post me back. For further details :-http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp
Page Two:-

```
<?php

  // ini_set("display_errors", "On");
 //header('content-type:application/json');

$id = $_GET["id"];

if ($id == "start")
{
    $con=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "rootwdp", "try");

    $numbers = array();
    $img_arr = array();
    $res = $con->query("select img_name, img_id from img");
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())

    // mysql_fetch_array() passes parameters from 0 
    { $numbers[]=$row; }

    echo json_encode($numbers);
}

?>
```

Comment: Sir...thanku for the quick answer....but the callback isnt working at all..that is the output of load_img.php....i guess it is right bcoz whn i used var dump(json_decode) it decoded it too...

Comment: Can u tell me the error bcoz i knw the  error is in php page itself...it works perfect for json files

Comment: <?php

//header('content-type:application/json');

$id=$_POST["id"];
if($id=="start")
{
include("connection.php");
$numbers=array();
$img_arr=array();
$i=mysql_query("select img_name,img_id from img");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($i))//mysql_fetch_array() passes parameters from 0
  {
    
   $numbers[]=$row;
   
   
  }
  echo json_encode($numbers);
}
  
?>

Comment: can you make to $id=$_GET['id']; and try once again

Comment: Still nthng happened

Comment: Still nthng happened

Comment: Sir still nthng happened

Comment: Its working for me very well. please check your code one by one. Now its all upto you.

Comment: JS + HTML code=>                        '<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script>
 $("#try").click(function()
 {
    $.getJSON("load_img.php", {"id":"start"}, function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
             alert(field.img_name);
        });
    });
 });
 </script>

</head>

<body>
 <button id="try" type="button">Try</button>

</body>
'

Comment: PHP code=>'    <body>
<?php

  // ini_set("display_errors", "On");
 header('Content-Type: application/json');

$id = $_GET["id"];

//if ($id == "start")
{
    $con=new mysqli("localhost", "root","","img_slider");

    $numbers = array();
    $img_arr = array();
    $res = $con->query("select img_name, img_id from img");
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())

    // mysql_fetch_array() passes parameters from 0 
         { $numbers[]=$row; }

        echo json_encode($numbers);
     }

     ?>
    </body> '

Answer (score -2):

```
$.getJSON("path to php file", {method: "*", "id":"start"})
                    .done(function (data) {

                            console.log(data)

                    });
//================in php=================================
if($_REQUEST['method'] == "your method" AND $_REQUEST['id'] ) {
//call your php function
}                   
//-------------------
//and put your php code in function 
//.. i hope this help you
```

Comment: Ahmed sir...i knw the format of this function...but i dnt understand where am i lacking so as to ensure a callback